# How do you crawl external links on a found page?

Tags: nutch

I used the example on installing nutch from their wiki. I was able to crawl multiple pages pulled from dmoz easily. But is there a configuration that can be done to crawl external links it finds on a page, or write those external links to a file to be crawled next?

What is the best way to follow links on a page to index that page as well with nutch? If I were executing the bin/nutch via python, could I get back all the external links it found, and create a new crawl list to run again? What would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure that the parameter 'db.ignore.external.links' is set to false. Also, in the file 'regex-urlfilter.txt', add rules for the external links you wish to be crawled OR add `+.` as the last rule. The `+.` rule will make the crawler follow ALL links. If you use that last option, beware that you risk crawling all the Web!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will play with the regex filter.txt file to get optimal results.