# Nutch crawling external links from a web page

Tags: nutch

I am using Apache Nutch for crawling websites. Nutch is not crawling links for external websites.

I have gone through this link [How do you crawl external links on a found page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019115/how-do-you-crawl-external-links-on-a-found-page) but it did not produce intended result.

Comment: You should probably mention the version of Nutch and show how it is configured.

Comment: I am using version 1.6. I have set 'false' for db.ignore.external.links in nutch-default.xml file. Do I need to set any other property